# Python - Read and append characters to the new write

Tags: python

I have a file named "Strings.txt" which contains the following format

```
text = text
```

Small sample of Strings.txt:

```
Incoming calls = See the Preferences
Incoming message from %@ = Incoming message from %@
Enter Your Password =
```

I want to read this file in Python insert some character/strings and write it to other file like "Format.strings"

The out put will be :

```
/* No comment test. */
"Incoming calls" = "See the Preferences";

/* No comment test. */
"Incoming message from %@" = "Incoming message from %@";

/* No comment test. */
"Enter Your Password" = "";
```

Here is my Python code:

```
prefix = '"'
suffix = '";'
comment = '/* No comment test. */'




f = codecs.open('Strings.txt', encoding="utf-16")
o = codecs.open('temp.strings', 'w')

for line in f:
    o.write(line.replace(' = ', '\" = \"' ))
f.close()
o.close()

h = codecs.open('temp.strings', 'r')
t = codecs.open('Format.strings', 'w') 
for l in h:
    t.write(comment + '\n')
    t.write('%s%s%s\n' % (prefix, l.rstrip('\n') , suffix))
    t.write("\n");

t.close()
h.close()
```

Is there a way to avoid using the "temp.strings" file(second reading and writing) and get the same result ?

Comment: If the file is small, read all of it, and do everything in memory. If it is not, there is no way, because files are stored in a way no insert can be done on them.

Comment: @Am.rez Thanks, they size would be dynamic .. sometimes small and sometimes large .. appreciated if you write your solution with doing everything in memory,Thanks

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the code carefully... The input and output files are different, therefore you can write directly to the output file.

Comment: You can also try using `output = StringIO();
o = codecs.EncodedFile(output, "utf-16")` instead of the temporary file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file t o read. Then replace the characters. Instead of writing to different file, write it to the Format.strings file!!

```
prefix = '"'
suffix = '";'
comment = '/* No comment test. */'

f = codecs.open('Strings.txt',"r")
t = codecs.open('Format.strings', 'w+') 

for line in f.readlines():
    t.writelines(comment + '\n')
    line = line.replace(' = ', '\" = \"' )
    t.writelines('%s%s%s\n' % (prefix, line.rstrip('\n') , suffix))
    t.writelines("\n")
f.close()
t.close()
```

Output in Format.strings:

```
/* No comment test. */
"Incoming calls" = "See the Preferences";

/* No comment test. */
"Incoming message from %@" = "Incoming message from %@";

/* No comment test. */
"Enter Your Password" = "";

/* No comment test. */
"Dial Plans" = "Disable Calls";

/* No comment test. */
"Details not available" = "Call Button";
```

Comment: The problem I see with your code is that no output encoding is declared in `t = codecs.open('Format.strings', 'w+') `: it will work with ASCII input, but fail with higher characters.

Comment: codecs is what @Benalison has used. Hence I retained the same.